# Sql Server 2008 R2 Management Studio Yet Another intellisense issue

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, intellisense, ssms

I have some issue I can't find any info about!

I did a clean install, and VS2010 was not yet installed when it occured!
My colleagues don't seem to have this issue while having exactly the same software!
Sql Server 2008 R2 is fully up to date with SP1 etc.

**The issue:** 
My intellisense works!
For example when I type `SELECT * FROM` --> right after the last space I see my schema or database or table names!

**What doesn't work is:**
When I continue `SELECT * FROM ma`" --> now the database "master" is selected! Normally when I type "." (a dot) I would get `SELECT * FROM master.`, but I just get `SELECT * FROM ma.`

This is SOOO annoying!!

I have fixed this in the past by installing a Management Studio from the NON R2 version, but I just have a fresh install and **I would like to know how to fix this, or at least know the cause?**

I hope I described my issue properly!

Kind regards,
Wim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavior was changed at some point. I have to type Enter and then the dot in SQL Server 2008 R2.

In SQL Server 2012, when you see the auto-complete list, you need another keystroke to actually select it (e.g. down-arrow), then the dot works. You may want to download SQL Server 2012 RC0 and see if the updated IntelliSense functionality is slightly better (though, admittedly, not perfect and still not how it used to work).

In case you're worried that SSMS 2012 is not worth your time yet, please see this question over on ASK SSC: http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/86305/sql-server-2012-ready-to-use.html

Comment: Hmmm ... I checked other people's Management Studio R2 at the office and they seem to have the same issue! So I was wrong in thinking it was a PEBKAC issue ....

Comment: Still ... if every R2 management studio has this issue, then I'm downgrading right away to the one that comes with the 2008 RTM!! Talking about loss of functionality :s

It seems like I'm nagging about something small, but now after every databasename or schemaname I have to type one extra keystroke!!! I go crazy when typing queries all day ...

Comment: uninstalled the R2 management studio and installed the RTM management studio! I have my functionality back! :)

Comment: Yeah it's funny how such a small change in functionality can be like a pebble in the shoe